# How to find public day in jalali calendar

Tags: npm, calendar, jalali-calendar

I want to find a public day in Jalali calendar, I use npm Jalali-moment with this code

```
var moment = require('jalali-moment');
moment().locale('fa').format('YYYY/M/D');
```

This site has done this which called [تاریخ امروز](https://8box.ir/time/today)  But I don't know how he did it.

Is there a way to do this without manually entering information like this site( [Garageband for windows](https://garagebandforwindows.org) )?

Comment: you should use API like a Farsicalendar website . I tested it was very good

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Jdf function There is a section on the Jdf site that writes full of Hijri dates and lunar dates.

[image]

Comment: Don't have this database?

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question, I used to want to do it before, but eventually I had to manually enter the information

Comment: Yeah I think I should do that. But do I want to see if anyone else does this?